# Node.js - Repetitive require('path'/'module') statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

My question is whether having multiple of the same require('path'/'module') statements negatively affects performance.

```
// Multiple require('path') statements
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app
  .route("/example")
  .get(require("./api/api.js").example.get)
  .put(require("./api/api.js").example.put)
  .post(require("./api/api.js").example.post)
  .delete(require("./api/api.js").example.delete);
```

in comparison to ..

```
// Single require('path') statement
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const api = require("./api/api.js");
app
  .route("/example")
  .get(api.example.get)
  .put(api.example.put)
  .post(api.example.post)
  .delete(api.example.delete);
```

Comment: Not sure about performance but the latter is definitely way easier to read.

Comment: Another way to improve readability imo is to use `const { example } = require('./api/api.js');` then each of your property references would just be `.get(example.get).put(example.put)` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may affect performance, but only by a miniscule amount. Multiple `require`s (or `import`s) of the same module does not run the module's code again - all it does is access the already-existing module's exports in memory. It's definitely not something to worry about *for the sake of performance*. It's very similar to accessing the same property of an object over and over again.

For readability, however, the second code is much clearer, though you could reduce repetitiveness even more (and improve performance by an insignificant amount) by extracting the `example` property first:

```
const { example } = require("./api/api.js");
app
  .route("/example")
  .get(example.get)
  .put(example.put)
  .post(example.post)
  .delete(example.delete);
```

Comment: Haha, love how we suggested that at the same time :)